# How to change cameras in After effects

Tags: after-effects

I am creating some 3D sences but i am taking one shot from left side but how i can then choose other camera to view from other sides. Like changing cameras that are on different sides.
http://www.videocopilot.net/flightschool/flight_control/

If you look at 0.34 you can see that he made same plane shot from different sides. ( He didnt explained it in video )

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. That question is about AE rendering the active camera instead of a camera layer - this question is specifically about rendering multiple camera angles together.

Comment: If you want to render different views at the same time, drag the comp into another composition. Make it a 3D layer and turn on continuous rasterisation or whatever it's called (the little sun icon). Add your new camera to this comp and it will see the contents of the nested comp from its own viewpoint. Rinserepeat, then you can render as many views as you like.

Comment: If you want to jump from one camera to another just split the camera layer **shift-ctrl/cmd-d** and reposition the new camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to export by clip - i.e., set your camera to angle 1 and export your first X frames (where 'X' is how many frames you want that shot to last for). Then, adjust your camera to angle 2 and export the next set of frames (however long you want that shot, etc.). These clips can then be combined in Premiere Pro (or After Effects) and you can easily add sound effects, etc. They are easy to timeline edit this way because they'll be already rendered and thus, you can work with the project in a much quicker way.